# Se duplica la información al traer los datos jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo un problema y es que cuando accedo a esta información llega repetida y no se porque, de donde la llamo no esta repetida, a que se deberá?

Gracias

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu html, para poder ver mejor el problema?

Comment: Estás usando un selector de clase (empieza por punto `.`), puede que haya dos elementos con esa clase que tengan escrito `26cms` cada uno.